# Redirecting a port to a remote server on windows

Tags: windows, port, port-forwarding, redirection

I only have command line access to a server and I'm not allowed to disable the antivirus (which blocks netcat). What I would like to do is have a program that listens on port A and when a remote computer connects to it redirect all input/output of that socket to another server on a different port. Basically a small proxy. Is there anything that will let me do this from command line? If not I could try coding something simple that does this with C++

Answer (score 1):

You can try `rinetd`.